# How to plot a one to many function on matplotlib in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, plot

Very simple, if I plot x^2+y^2=z it makes this shape on python it will make this shape:

[image: 1]

When I would like to plot it this way:

[image: 2]

Below is my code, I am new so I copied it from the internet and have changed the line with the function to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-4*np.pi,4*np.pi,50)
y = np.linspace(-4*np.pi,4*np.pi,50)
z = x**2+y**2
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Also, how do I make it more high definition and smooth, this is a graph of z=sin(x)

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a 2D mathematical domain with [**`numpy.meshgrid`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), then you can compute the surface on that domain:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = X**2 + Y**2
```

In order to increase the smoothness of the surface, you have in increase the number of point `N` you use to compute `x` and `y` arrays:

### Complete code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 50

x = np.linspace(-4*np.pi, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.linspace(-4*np.pi, 4*np.pi, N)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = X**2 + Y**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

[image]